# how to correctly listen to snapshot from firestore and firebase auth in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm quite confused with how the flow should be with the `firebase auth` and `firestore snapshot`. In my mind, since snapshot is sending me the update for the document, then I should start the snapshot after the user is login, or maybe after they refresh their browser.

So, is it correct that I should implement all of my snapshot in here?

```
//firebase import

//all initialization
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
    //do all snapshot
    } else {
    //not signed in
    //redirect to login page
    //should I unsubscribe my snapshot? how do I do it?
    }
}
```

Am I understanding correctly, that after the user is logged in, then the `onAuthStateChanged` will be triggered? if they refresh their browser or log out, then `onAuthStateChanged` will also be triggered.

also, how could I unsubscribe my snapshot when the user is changed? and subscribe again with the current user?

is it possible for `firebase auth` rather than changed from `null to exists` or `exists to null` but, from User A to User B directly? if yes, how could I anticipate it with my `snapshot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I understanding correctly, that after the user is logged in, then the onAuthStateChanged will be triggered?

Yes, changing the authentication state triggers `onAuthStateChanged`.

> if they refresh their browser or log out, then onAuthStateChanged will also be triggered.

Yes. When the page loads, Firebase tried to restore any previously signed in user. No matter whether tis succeeds or not, it'll call `onAuthStateChanged` when this is done: either with a valid user when it was able to restore the credentials, or with `null` if there was no signed-in user before, or if it was unable to restore the credentials.

> also, how could I unsubscribe my snapshot when the user is changed? and subscribe again with the current user?

This very much depends on how you subscribe to the snapshot. If you subscribe in the `if (user)` branch of `onAuthStateChanged`, you can unsubscribe whenever `onAuthStateChanged` gets called again.

Something like:

```
let unsubscribe;
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (unsubscribe) {
    unsubscribe();
    unsubscribe = null;
  }
  if (user) {
    unsubscribe = onSnapshot(....); 
  } else {
    //not signed in
    //redirect to login page
    //should I unsubscribe my snapshot? how do I do it?
  }
}
```

> is it possible for firebase auth rather than changed from null to exists or exists to null but, from User A to User B directly?

Yes, this is possible.

> if yes, how could I anticipate it with my snapshot?

We did this above already by putting the unsubscribe logic outside of the `if` and `else` blocks.

---

I recommend giving the `onAuthStateChanged` listener a try and inspecting its behavior in practice, and reporting back if you can't get it to work.

Comment: thank you so much. now everything makes sense for me. the flow seems much more beautiful. since its already been `unsubscribed` whenever it can, so I don't need to `unsubscribe` again in the `else` section.

Comment: Nice and extensive answer @FrankVanPuffelen!